# Do you need to scan the 30th anniversary mario amiibo everytime to use the extra stuff

Tags: super-mario-maker

Do you need to scan the 30th anniversary mario amiibo everytime to use the extra stuff that the amiibo gives.  Or can you only do it once, meaning you could borrow it from someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Super Mario Maker, when you scan an Amiibo, it will unlock the corresponding costume for use with the Mystery Mushroom. However, when using the 30th Anniversary Mario Amiibo, you will need to scan it each time you want that mushroom. You could borrow the Amiibo from someone to implement it in one level but if you want it in another level you will need to borrow the Amiibo again.